# How to use CHEERIO.js for this HTML?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

```
<div class="A">
<section class="B" data-vr-zone="B">
    <header class="C"> BarFoo</header>
    <ul class="list">
        <li data-vr-contentbox=""> 
            <a href="http://www.foobar.com/.../html">
                <small>BarBar</small> 
                <span>Foo Bar foobarbar FooFoo?</span>
            </a>

        </li>
        <li data-vr-contentbox=""> 
            <a href="http://www.foofoobar.com/.../html">
                <small>BarBarBar</small> 
                <span>Foo foo FooFoo?</span>
            </a>

        </li>
```

I want to access the url in the HREF attribute. And the text in the SPAN -- Of only the first list item.

What I have works but I'm looking to learn a better way.

`var url = $('div .A').children().children().children().children()[0].attribs.href;`

`var title = $('div .A').children().children().children().children()[0].children[2].children[0].data;`

Answer (score 6):

You want to use a better selector string to target the element & attribute of interest. Exactly how vague or precise you go involves trade-offs of coupling too tighly to the DOM structure and thus some irrelevant change to the HTML means your selector doesn't match anymore or using too vague a selector and matching more stuff than you intend.

- vaguest: `'a'` (find every anchor)
- `'.A a'` (every anchor inside the div class="A")
- Recommended: `'.A li a'` (must be part of a list)
- crazy specific: `'div.A section.B ul.list li a'`

.

```
var link = $('.A li a');
var href = link.attr('href');
var spanText = link.find('span').first().text();
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks! sorry had to make an edit there is more than one item in the list so when selecting the 'SPAN' it prints out the text of every 'SPAN'. How do you grab just the first 'SPAN' under the first 'a'. Would assume 'div.A section.B ul.list li a span'.text()'... but this prints out all the span ojects. find('span') also gets all span not just the first one

Comment: You can use the ':first-child' pseudo-class selector or the `.first()` jQuery/Cheerio method.

Comment: ahh yes the .first() works!  the ':first-child' pseudo-class selector doesn't work and research tells me that it will only work if the target is actually the first-child and in this case 'small' is the 'first-child'.